# PHP: conditionally cancel destructor

Tags: php, destructor

I would like to have a class's destructor execute only once, no matter how many times it's called during the execution of the script (some php version of the javascript [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)).

I have a scenario like so:

```
class A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $b = new B();       // and do some stuff with B
        if ( condition )
        {
            $c = new C();   // and do some stuff with C
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    function __destruct()
    {
        echo "B: DESTRUCTOR!\n";
    }
    // …
}

class C extends B
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "C: CONSTRUCTOR!\n";
    }
    public function i()
    {
        echo "C->i()\n";
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

**A** is triggering **B**'s destructor (because it creates an instance of B), and **C** might trigger **B**'s destructor (because C extends B) if it is called from A. I need the last triggerer of B::__destruct() to be the only caller.

The reason for this is because B's destructor sets HTTP Response headers and then delivers the Response body; if the destructor is called more than once, PHP errors out because headers can't be sent after the body has started. I am in a shared-host situation so I cannot make configuration changes or install packages (like PECL's [`HttpResponse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php)).

I am aware of [`headers_sent()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php), so I *could* add a test within B's destructor on the output of that, but I don't think that is the best solution.

Comment: Destructors are there to tidy up an instance before it's deleted. PHP does most of this for you anyway so they're rarely very useful. If you need the class to actually _do_ something, don't put it in the destructor.

Comment: The reason I'm putting it in the destructor is so that it will be automatically called at the end (and then each child doesn't have to remember to call/execute the destructor's logic).

Comment: @jacob: What is it you want to do in the destructor? As Mike already said, destructors are rarely useful.

Comment: @halfdan The destructor sends the response: It sets response headers and outputs the response body.

Comment: @halfdan, emphasis on *automatically*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function __destruct()
{
  static $runonce=false;
  if($runonce!==false)return;
  $runonce=true;
    echo "B: DESTRUCTOR!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned in my question, I've already thought of this solution and am asking about a different one.